# ¿Cómo puedo guardar una imagen con Codeigniter, Ajax, Uppy JS?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter-4

Tengo mi formulario para que pueda guardar una imagen, agregué las rutas correspondientes al archivo de configuración de rutas de Codeigniter, pero no sé si por lo menos está mandando la solicitud a mi controlador, porque no me regresa nada. Adjunto mi código.

**Formulario**

```
<!--begin::Body-->
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      action="<?= site_url('admin/works/uploadImage') ?>">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="uploadThumbnail">Thumbnail</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="uppy" id="uploadThumbnail">
                    <button id="imageThumbnail"
                            class="uppy-btn btn btn-light-primary font-weight-bold">
                        Cargar miniatura
                    </button>
                    <div class="uppy-dashboard"></div>
                    <div class="uppy-progress"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="workTitle">Título del Trabajo del
                                   Portafolio</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="la la-exclamation-triangle icon-lg"></i>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="workTitle"
                       id="workTitle">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-center">
        <button id="saveWork" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Guardar
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
<!--end::Body-->
```

**Controlador Codeigniter**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Controllers\Backend;
    
    use App\Controllers\BaseController;
    
    class Works extends BaseController {
        public function index() {
            $data['title'] = 'Trabajos del Portafolio';
            return view('backend/dashboard/works', $data);
        }
        
        public function uploadedImage() {
            if ($this->request->isAJAX()) {
            echo 'yes';
            }
        }
    }
```

**Ajax**

```
Uppy.Core({
    debug      : true,
    autoProceed: false,
    
    restrictions: {
        allowedFileTypes: ['image/*', 'video/!*']
    }
}).use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
    proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy: false,
    target                     : '#uploadThumbnail' + ' .uppy-dashboard',
    inline                     : false,
    replaceTargetContent       : true,
    showProgressDetails        : true,
    note                       : 'No filetype restrictions.',
    height                     : 470,
    browserBackButtonClose     : true,
    trigger                    : '#uploadThumbnail' + ' .uppy-btn'
}).use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:8080/admin/works/uploadImage',
    method  : 'post',
}).on('upload-success', (file, response) => {
    
    console.log(response.uploadURL);
    console.log(file.name);
    
});
```

Al tener todo este no sé si al menos está mandando la solicitud correctamente o que me pueda falta, en el `console.log(response.uploadURL);` recibo undefined, si alguien trabajó con esta libreria para subir imágenes, requiero de ayuda.